# How to trim a list in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am kinda new to python/pandas.

I converted a json to a csv. Now one column still looks like this and contains several attributes.

```
                                            location
0  {'country': 'United States', 'state': 'New Jer...
1  {'country': 'Australia', 'state': 'Queensland'...
2  {'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Texas',...
3  {'country': 'Australia', 'state': None, 'city'...
4  {'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Califor...
```

Basically what I want is a simple column only containing the value for country as strings. So it would looks somewhat like this:

```
        location
0  United States
1  Australia
2  United States
3  Australia
4  United States
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'location']))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If column is filled by dictionaries use:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'location']))
<class 'dict'>

df['location'] = df['location'].str.get('country')
print (df)
        location
0  United States
1      Australia
2  United States
3      Australia
4  United States
```

If there are strings:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'location']))
<class 'str'>

import ast

df['location'] = df['location'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str.get('country')

print (df)
        location
0  United States
1      Australia
2  United States
3      Australia
4  United States
```

Comment: Quick follow up question: Your answere worked perfectly. But now I get an additional first column called "Unnamed: 0" which simply contains the index (I used your second way with strings). I can just drop it but is there a way to not create it in the first place?

Comment: @BenW - Values are like `print (df.index)` ? And you need avoid it if write to csv file ? Then use `df.to_csv(file, index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a data frame directly from a list of dictionaries with similar keys. Therefore you just have to get the items in the column into a list form before building your new data frame. The keys in the list of dicts become the new columns.

This can be solved with a single line of code -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':[{'country': 'United States', 'state': 'New Jersey'},
                               {'country': 'Australia', 'state': 'Queensland'},
                               {'country': 'United States', 'state': 'Texas'}]})


#Building a dataframe directly from a list of dictionaries with similar keys
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(df['Location'].values))
print(df2)
```

```
         country       state
0  United States  New Jersey
1      Australia  Queensland
2  United States       Texas
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Json directly like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json ('jsnotation.json')
```

df is now a dataframe. So printing will givie output:

```
    Country    State
0   USA        Texas
1   Australia  Qeensland
2   USA        California
```

Now you can get your desired result like:

```
print(df['country'])

   Country    
0   USA       
1   Australia 
2   USA
```

To change the header:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Country': 'Location'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if you ran:

`type(df["Location"][0])`

you'd get "str" as an output (df being the dataframe of the csv you read in).

That being said, there are 2 ways you'd be able to handle this issue:

1. Convert the strings to dictionaries and extract the key/value pairs into columns

You can do this by running:

`import ast`

`df["location"] = df["location"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))`

This would take each row in your dataframe and convert the string representations into the required dictionary data type for wrangling. Next we can extract the values into columns manually by running (taking "country" column as an example):

`df['location'] = df['location'].str.get('country')`

Which will give you your desired result.

2. Avoid converting your data into csv and read in the json file directly

The Pandas library includes a pd.read_json function that can handle .json to pandas dataframes.

`pd.read_json (r'Path where you saved the JSON file\File Name.json')`